# Unable to Update contact on Form Submit

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am working on Sitecore 9.0.2 and created a custom Update contact logic where I am  storing Firstname, email and Custom facet to xDB. This fails if the person filling the form is an existing user.

Log says:

```
2019-06-03 14:00:45.704 +10:00 [Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.SetFacetOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Facet]: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #3, AlreadyExists, Contact {c536d93f-1dad-0000-0000-0592c2e3e51c}, RYIForm
2019-06-03 14:00:45.846 +10:00 [Error] ["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException: Operation #3, AlreadyExists, Contact {c536d93f-1dad-0000-0000-0592c2e3e51c}, RYIForm
```

I was getting this issue with two facets: `PhoneNumbers` and `Customfacet` when i added `Phonenumber` to `ExpandOptions` the error was resolved for phone numbers but it still persists for `RYIForm`. Code snippet below:

```
var expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation, CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList, RYIFacets.DefaultFacetKey, "PhoneNumbers");
```

Thanks,
Samridhi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check first if the facet already exists, the code to get or create the RYIFacets facet could like this:

```
var contact = context.Contact;
var facet = contact.GetFacet<RYIFacets>(RYIFacets.DefaultFacetKey);

if (facet == null)
{
facet = new RYIFacets();
}
```

When working with a facet, not all data is always loaded, so check. See also https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/set-contact-facets.html  and  https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/access-contact-and-interaction-data-from-activity-type.html

Comment: Thanks Jan, the above snippet resolved my issue.